# Chrome Extension with Service worker, update badge from a 'push' event

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker

I have recently built a Chrome Extension that is coupled with a service worker, which recives push notifications via FCM, this is all working and my Service worker triggers correctly.

I want to be able to set the Chrome Extension Badge text from this function, as my server is updating the extension with the correct count.

Here is the function that I am currently using.

```
self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
  if (event.data) {
    let data = event.data.json();

    if (data.count){
        // This is the only function that I can see when I debug the chrome obj
        chrome.runtime.getBackgroundClient().then((bgClient) => {
            console.log(bgClient)
        })
    }
  }
});
```

I am aware of the 
`chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: count});`
function but this does not seem to be available from within the service worker, not can I see a way of accessing my background scripts.

Comment: Use the standard BroadcastChannel or MessageChannel API.

Comment: @wOxxom From what I have seen, these API's need you to first send a message to the Service worker in order for it to respond? That isnt currently possible as this is a Push event and the background script has no clue when this is triggered

Comment: Well, you can notify the background script for example by registering a chrome.webNavigation listener on extension's own URL pattern so the service worker would fetch chrome-extension://id/?hooray, then the background script would open the channel.